# Is "Fn key" not defined in X Window in "X11/keysymdef.h"?

Tags: x11

I tried to simulate keypress by Xlib, but I can't find out where <kbd>Fn</kbd> key was defined in " [keysymdef.h](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/ucs/keysymdef.h) ".

**If** it really wasn't defined in Xlib, are there any workarounds for it ?

Comment: @BЈовић That is **function key** not **Fn key**

Answer (score 7):

<kbd>Fn</kbd> works differently from modifiers such as <kbd>Shift</kbd>: it's typically caught [inside the keyboard controller or in the BIOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fn_key#Technical_details), and the combined (<kbd>Fn</kbd> + other) keypress is sent over the bus as a single signal. That means that X11, or the OS for that matter, doesn't even get to see that <kbd>Fn</kbd> was pressed.

Comment: Great explanation! But no workarounds? such as [XTestFakeKeyEvent](http://linux.die.net/man/3/xtestfakekeyevent)(Dsp, **"Put special value"**, True, 0);

Comment: @KevinDongNaiJia: none that I'm aware of, but then my X11 programming is limited to a day's trying and deciding it's not for me :)